# GraphQL - Cannot move resolver to a separate file

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I have searched the forum for anything related to customizing GraphQL in Strapi v4 but found nothing.

**Note**: my GraphQL skills is a novice.

I extended my GraphQL resolver in Strapi v4, and it worked fine as long as the resolver was in the same file as "index.ts." I want to modularize my GraphQL code by moving the resolver into a separate file.  When I did that, I kept getting the following error:

> "resolvers" is defined in the resolver but not in the schema.

Below is my resolver embedded in the file index.ts, which ***works fine without any issue***.

**index.ts**

```
  /**
   * Extend register for GraphQL
   */
  register({ strapi }): void {
    // customized programmatically using GraphQL's extension
    const extensionService = strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension");
    const UID = "api::truth-lending-disclosure.truth-lending-disclosure";

    
    extensionService.use(({ strapi }) => ({
      typeDefs: ``,
      resolvers: {
        Query: {
          truthLendingDisclosures: async (parent, args, context) => {
  
            // toEntityResponse method to allow us to convert our response
            // to the appropriate format before returning the data.
            const { toEntityResponseCollection } = strapi
              .plugin("graphql")
              .service("format").returnTypes;

            // define level to populate
            let _populate = {
              body: {
                populate: {
                  section: true,
                },
              },
            };

            // using shadow CRUD from entity service to fetch data
            let entities = await strapi.entityService.findMany(UID, {
              populate: _populate,
            });

            // find and replace placeholder with key-value risCustomerTermDataMap
            // return the result as JSON string
            let stringResult = dataSubstitution(
              JSON.stringify(entities), // convert an object to JSON string
              risCustomerTermDataMap
            );

            // conver JSON string back object
            let objectResult = JSON.parse(stringResult);
            debugger;

            return toEntityResponseCollection(objectResult);
          },
        },
      },
    }));
  },
```

Moved the resolvers logic into a separate file mycustom.resolvers.ts

**mycustom.resolvers.ts**

```
import { risCustomerTermDataMap } from "../../../../libs/common/risaCustomerTermDataMap";
import { dataSubstitution } from "../../../../libs/helpers/dataSubstitution";

// the logic in this file does not work with index.ts yet
// keep getting "resolvers" define in resolvers, but not in schema.
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    truthLendingDisclosures: async (parent, args, context) => {
      console.log("***** GraphQL Resolvers*****");

      const UID = "api::truth-lending-disclosure.truth-lending-disclosure";

      // toEntityResponse method to allow us to convert our response
      // to the appropriate format before returning the data.
      const { toEntityResponseCollection } = strapi
        .plugin("graphql")
        .service("format").returnTypes;

      // define level to populate
      let _populate = {
        body: {
          populate: {
            section: true,
          },
        },
      };

      // using shadow CRUD from entity service to fetch data
      let entities = await strapi.entityService.findMany(UID, {
        populate: _populate,
      });

      // find and replace placeholder with key-value risCustomerTermDataMap
      // return the result as JSON string
      let stringResult = dataSubstitution(
        JSON.stringify(entities), // convert an object to JSON string
        risCustomerTermDataMap
      );

      // conver JSON string back object
      let objectResult = JSON.parse(stringResult);
      debugger;

      return toEntityResponseCollection(objectResult);
    },
  },
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I got it to work.

I modified my resolver in the external file "mycustom.resolvers.ts" to  this:

**filename: mycustom.resolvers.ts**

```
export const truthLendingDisclosureResolvers = {
  Query: {
    async truthLendingDisclosures(): Promise<any> {
      console.log("***** external resolver *****");

      const UID = "api::truth-lending-disclosure.truth-lending-disclosure";

      // toEntityResponse method to allow us to convert our response
      // to the appropriate format before returning the data.
      const { toEntityResponseCollection } = strapi
        .plugin("graphql")
        .service("format").returnTypes;

      // define level to populate
      let _populate = {
        body: {
          populate: {
            section: true,
          },
        },
      };

      // using shadow CRUD from entity service to fetch data
      let entities = await strapi.entityService.findMany(UID, {
        populate: _populate,
      });

      // find and replace placeholder with key-value risCustomerTermDataMap
      // return the result as JSON string
      let stringResult = dataSubstitution(
        JSON.stringify(entities), // convert an object to JSON string
        risCustomerTermDataMap
      );

      // conver JSON string back object
      let objectResult = JSON.parse(stringResult);

      return toEntityResponseCollection(objectResult, {
        args: {},
        resourceUID: UID,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

and modified the "index.ts" to this:

**filename: index.ts**

```
register({ strapi }): void {
    // customized programmatically using GraphQL's extension
    const extensionService = strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension");
    const UID = "api::truth-lending-disclosure.truth-lending-disclosure";

    // disable an action on a query
    // extensionService.shadowCRUD(UID).disableAction("find");

    extensionService.use(({ strapi }) => ({
      typeDefs: ``,
      resolvers: truthLendingDisclosureResolvers,
    }));
  },
```